# Vite dependencies not working with dynamic loaded module

Tags: reactjs, vite

I use a webassembly @swc which is loaded dynamically.

```
const swcWasmWeb = await import("@swc/wasm-web");
```

Vite does not copy the file to ..\node_modules\.vite\deps

How can i force vite to do it?

I have tried it with *assetsInclude* in the vite.config.ts but it does not work.